# How to generate enterprise WSDL files from salesforce?

Tags: soap-api, licenses, wsdl

I need to generate enterprise WSDL file in salesForce, but I don't see this option in
    Setup -> Develop -> API.

I just see a page telling me for more information  visit        http://developer.salesforce.com.
     I'm using 30 day trial, would that be the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Trial version accounts do not provide WSDL. You need to have developer or enterprise account to generate WSDL for your environment.

If you are not able to see it in the options then it might be because you may not be logged in as admin or with Modify All Data permission and that might be stopping you from generating the WSDL. Else the procedure is quite direct Setup->Develop->API->Select the type of WSDL you wish to generate.
Attaching an snapshot for the same

[image]

Comment: I have already registered for developer edition, but I can't find any link for generating wsdl files in this version either. Can you please tell me where and how I can generate this file. I would appreciate it if you could attach an image of it.

Comment: It might be because you may not be logged in as admin or with Modify All Data permission and that might be stopping you from generating the WSDL.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a developer edition, but can't see the WSDL links for some reason (you should be able to), you can go directly to the WSDL URLs.

For the Enterprise WSDL:

> https://**serverinstance**.salesforce.com/setup/build/generateEnterpriseWsdl.apexp

For the Partner WSDL:

> https://**serverinstance**.salesforce.com/soap/wsdl.jsp

You will need to replace serverinstance with your pod. E.g. na2

Make sure your browser has a valid session when requesting the WSDLs so the correct cookie is sent with the request.

Note that the Enterprise WSDL is customised to the Org it was generated for. So if you have made schema changes (added a field or custom object) it will change this WSDL.